# How to convert .wav file into an image for neural network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, librosa

I am trying to perform sound classification using neural network and would like to convert the audio file of 4 seconds in .wav file format to be converted to an image.

I would prefer to use Librosa library. Also I would like to know how to read this image and provide it as an input to any CNN model.

I did find similar post here but they don't solve my issue.

This is what I have tried so far:

```py
y, sr = librosa.load('36902-3-2-0.wav')
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y, sr, n_mels=128, fmax=8000)
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=np.max), fmax=8000)
plt.savefig('mel.png')
```

I get this image:

[image]

And when I try to read the image using `matplotlib.pyplot` or `cv2`, all I get is an array filled with `255` value:

```sh
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       ...,
```

Link to audio file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BBgOxKy2-JMOHa90DCeFVLgoA7pEblVg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you don't want your question downvoted, follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Specifically: "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: This is helpful for that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to add the audio file to my question.

Comment: For example if you are asking about a wav file, provide a wav file, or it is not reproducible.

Comment: Use a github link to add audio file, for example.

Comment: Also, read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331598/dodging-downvotes-by-deletion-and-repost

Comment: Added a link to audio file. I hope now you anyone can reproduce the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly normal - you are looking at the white border around the sides and `(255,255,255)` is white.

Try looking around coordinates `200,200`:

```
print(array[200:210, 200:210])

array([[[ 96,  87, 235],
        [ 96,  87, 235],
        [ 96,  87, 235],
        [ 95,  90, 237],
        [ 95,  90, 237],
        ...
        ...
```

Or look at the mean:

```
print(array.mean())

161.20984439300412
```